# How to check is my MediaBrowserSessionService is running or not

Tags: android, media

I am implemented a music player but my problem is that when i open app after closing with back button music is stop automatically.I want to check is my MediaBrowserSessionService is running or not or tell me other method.

```
private static final int STATE_PAUSED = 0;
private static final int STATE_PLAYING = 1;
private int mCurrentState;
private MediaBrowserCompat mMediaBrowserCompat;
private MediaControllerCompat mMediaControllerCompat;

private MediaBrowserCompat.ConnectionCallback mMediaBrowserCompatConnectionCallback = new MediaBrowserCompat.ConnectionCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onConnected() {
        super.onConnected();
        try {
            mMediaControllerCompat = new MediaControllerCompat(MainActivity.this, mMediaBrowserCompat.getSessionToken());
            mMediaControllerCompat.registerCallback(mMediaControllerCompatCallback);
            setSupportMediaController(mMediaControllerCompat);
            Log.i("Kunal","Kunal");
            MediaControllerCompat mediaControllerCompat=getSupportMediaController();
            Log.d("Controller", String.valueOf(mediaControllerCompat));
            Log.d("PlayBackState", String.valueOf(getSupportMediaController().getPlaybackState()));


        } catch( RemoteException e ) {

        }
    }
};




private MediaControllerCompat.Callback mMediaControllerCompatCallback = new MediaControllerCompat.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onMetadataChanged(MediaMetadataCompat metadata) {
        super.onMetadataChanged(metadata);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlaybackStateChanged(PlaybackStateCompat state) {
        super.onPlaybackStateChanged(state);
        if( state == null ) {
            return;
        }


        switch( state.getState() ) {
            case PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING: {
                mCurrentState = STATE_PLAYING;
                MainActivity.this.startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,BackgroundAudioService.class));
                break;
            }
            case PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED: {
                mCurrentState = STATE_PAUSED;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getPermission();
    settingFirstSong();

        Log.i("Service","Running");
        mMediaBrowserCompat = new MediaBrowserCompat(this, new ComponentName(this, BackgroundAudioService.class),
                mMediaBrowserCompatConnectionCallback, this.getIntent().getExtras());
        mMediaBrowserCompat.connect();

    // Log.d("Controller", String.valueOf(mediaControllerCompat));

    /*if(getSupportMediaController().getPlaybackState().getState()==2)
    {
        getSupportMediaController().getTransportControls().playFromMediaId(CurrentlyPlayingSongData.getTrackPath(), null);
        getSupportMediaController().getTransportControls().seekTo(sharedPreferences.getInt("position",0));

    }*/

    songList = new SongList(this);
    songDataArrayList = songList.getData();

    BitmapExtraction bitmapExtraction = new BitmapExtraction(this, songDataArrayList);
    bitmapExtraction.bitmapExtraction();

    View bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
    BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
    behavior.setHideable(false);

    artistList = new ArtistList(this);
    artistDatas = artistList.getData();

    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        AddDataToArtistDB addDataToArtistDB = new AddDataToArtistDB(this, artistDatas);
        addDataToArtistDB.start();
    }

            Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
            ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
            PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
            TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


}
```

This is my implemetation when i open app again it executes

```
    getSupportMediaController().getTransportControls().playFromMediaId("any.mp3", null);
```

again and my player is play song from starting what i do??

My error

```
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.media.session.PlaybackStateCompat android.support.v4.media.session.MediaControllerCompat.getPlaybackState()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at com.techweblearn.musicplayer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:115)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2402)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2509) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:153) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
```

Comment: `"I want to check is my MediaBrowserSessionService is running or not "`, what for?

Comment: When i open app music is stopped when it executed startservice() .  So i check if MediaBrowserService is running the not executed code

Comment: i have no idea what you are talking about...

Comment: When i close my app MediaBrowserService is stopped automatically  what i do.

Comment: so whats wrong if it is stopped? what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: I want it cannot be stop like other music player eg Google play

Comment: I add my code which has implementation, please read the code and what i do now

Comment: so you have lots of methods to get the current status before calling `playFromMediaId()`: getPlaybackState() / getPlaybackInfo() / getMetadata() / getQueue()

Comment: they all give me NullPointerException

Comment: because you need non null `MediaControllerCompat` object, if you call them on null object you will get `NullPointerException`

Comment: How to get MediaControllerCompat when my MediaBrowserService cannot be initialize

Comment: what you mean by `"cannot be initialize"`?

Comment: i add my error ..When i call getSupportMediaController().getPlaybackState().getState(); NullPointerException error accured

Comment: so you can call `getSupportMediaController().getTransportControls().playFromMediaId("any.mp3", null);` but cannot call `getSupportMediaController().getPlaybackState().getState();` ?

Comment: when i call getSupportMediaController().getPlaybackState().getState(); It gives null pointer exception

Comment: so you call it in a wrong place - did you call `setSupportMediaController` before? why dont you split it into several statements to see where is the `null` pointer? if you have `a().b().c().d().e()` how do you want to find what method returns `null` ?

Comment: ok, i will try this

Comment: get NullPointerException when i call .getPlaybackState();

Comment: so what is null actually: `MediaControllerCompat`?

Comment: No  'PlayBackStateCompat' is null

Comment: you call `controller.getPlaybackState()` and you got `NPE` right? so controller is `null`, just debug your code step-bystep if you have no experience in finding `NPE`

Comment: When i call ` MediaControllerCompat playbackStateCompat=getSupportMediaController();` it cannot be null  but when call  getSupportMediaController(),getPlayBackState(); it null

Comment: `MediaControllerCompat playbackStateCompat` ??? it make no sense, just do: `MediaControllerCompat controller = getSupportMediaController();` then use `Log.d` to log the value of `controller`, then call `controller.getPlaybackState()` etc

Comment: PlaybackStateCompat playbackStateCompat=getSupportMediaController().getPlaybackState(); give NPE

Comment: 'code'  PlaybackStateCompat playbackStateCompat=getSupportMediaController().getPlaybackState(); 'code'

Comment: i already told you: why do you chain those calls?  `getSupportMediaController().getPlaybackS‌​tate()` ??? just do: `MediaControllerCompat controller = getSupportMediaController();` then use `Log.d` to log the value of `controller`, then call `PlaybackStateCompat state = controller.getPlaybackState()` etc

Comment: ok, I will try this

Comment: yes, you right my `MediaControllerCompat` is null and give NPE now how to solve this problem.

Comment: i already told you: call `setSupportMediaController` before

Comment: Now, `MediaControllerCompat` cannot null but 'PlayBackStateCompat' give me null.

Comment: i only see `com.techweblearn.musicplayer.MainActivity.onCreate` i think this discussion is really pointless...

Comment: first read this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/index.html